# libnfs is slower while using in both context full access and context free access

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import libnfs
nfs = libnfs.NFS('nfs://127.0.0.1/tmp/')
a = nfs.open('/test-context-full', mode='w+')
a.write("Test string")
a.close()
print(nfs.open('/test-context-full', mode='r').read())
```

Wile running this code it stuck in **nfs = libnfs.NFS('nfs://127.0.0.1/tmp/')** this line?

Comment: Please provide error or output you got

Comment: There is no error shows. stuck on that line. I also tried with shell. same issue @ShanteshwarInde

Answer (score -1):

This has happened because `/tmp/` does not exist.